# EJS: Testing of included ejs files

Tags: unit-testing, mocha.js, ejs

my express app uses one path ("/") to display a huge page which was build using several includes. To avoid confusion, I would like to test each and every ejs file on its own. But as these ejs-includes are not reachable from the express app, I have no clue how to perform that task.

```
 - index.ejs   
   - mainMenu.ejs
   - systemsTable.ejs
     - systemRow.ejs
     - systemStatusIcon.ejs
     - systemName.ejs
     - ....
```

The more complex the index.ejs file gets the more I would like to test its parts. But how can I test the result of systemStatusIcon.ejs?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Without any knowledge of what your code looks like, the I suggest setting up a configuration JSON file of test data objects each containing:

- the EJS file path to be tested
- render input data
- an array of regular expressions to test against the rendered output

Then your test code can iterate over these objects and render and test each in turn.

### Example Template Rendering

A simple piece of code to render a template looks like this:

```
const ejs = require('ejs');

let template = `
value is: <%- value %>
`;

const renderData = {
    value: 123
};
const output = ejs.render(template, renderData);

console.log(output);
```

With output:

```
> node index.js

value is: 123
```

What renderData will be required is dependent on your existing templates. Template errors will be thrown as standard JS errors.

You could also use the renderFile function to do the loading for you.

```
ejs.renderFile(filename, data, options, function(err, str){
    // str => Rendered HTML string
});
```

EJS docs can be found at: https://ejs.co/

Comment: Hi @Russopotomus, the question is how to call the ejs file and retrieve the result in the test framework.

Comment: Hi @AntonSack - I've added examples of how to render an ejs template to the answer. Hope this helps.